# I am using django framework. I am new to this. I just want to show image file on my home page

Tags: django

I've written my settings.py file as:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/me/project/app/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/app/static/'
```

where in this static directory I've a directory named 'images' where I've stored my images which i wanted to show on my home page.

Here is my html code for image:

```
<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}images/lamb.jpg" width="600" height="450" />
```

still I did not get output. What am I missing , please help me
Thank you.

Comment: have you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ ?

Comment: @shashi Did you set MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get do more debugging. View the source of the page does img tag have a good looking URL? Past that URL into your browser, do you get a 404 error or something else?

Also there are other settings:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files

Specifically:
Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your INSTALLED_APPS.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

set `STATICFILES_DIRS` and make sure your image file is within `STATICFILES_DIRS` example in `/path/to/staticfiles_dirs/images/lamb.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your URLS are allowing the static files.
Adding something like this to your `urls.py` could work.

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$',
         'django.views.static.serve',
         {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True, }),
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$',
         'django.views.static.serve',
         {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True, }),
)
```

This is only recommend for running on your local machine and not in a live environment.